# Single Record vs Bulk Records Insert - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am getting the following error, when I try to populate the context object and save/insert all the records at once.

{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*T8*_2D83E3D3'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T8'. The duplicate key value is (AWLS0757043072).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

```
var proxy = new AREntities();
foreach (var a in b)
{
    ..........
    proxy.AddtoXYZ(data); //Please note 'data' inside foreach loop is different at all times. I am not adding same record multiple times.
}
proxy.SaveChanges();
```

But if i create the context for each record and then insert/save that record into db, it works fine. See below.

```
foreach (var a in b)
{
    ..........
    var proxy = new AREntities();
    proxy.AddtoXYZ(data);
    proxy.SaveChanges();
}
```

But the above code obviously screws the performance. I am trying to diagnose why i get the error in scenario 1. Any thoughts?

Here is the definition of key constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T8] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [C1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: i'm see **proxy.AddtoXYZ(data);** , Check a data object  C1 attribute value isn't duplicate in foreach loop

Comment: That was the First thing i checked, the C1 is different all the times.

Comment: do you have try rebuild EntityFrameWork Data Model ?

Comment: Did that as well. No success.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are adding the same entity multiple times and the primary key value is duplicated and as a result the error. The second way that you are doing it is correct. Only call save changes after the loop is complete, no performance impact.

Comment: Data inside foreach loop is different at all the times. I am not adding same item multiple times.

Comment: In the first case you are modifying the same object with different data. Just move save changes outside the loop

Comment: That is what i am trying to do and that is when i am getting the error.